# Big Sur - Ruby - Interrupted system call -- cannot load such file --

Tags: big-sur, ruby

After upgrading to Big Sur I am getting errors running my Ruby server rotating through different files either with

```
cannot load such file -- or Interrupted system call --
```

These errors rotate various files each time I run bundle exec rackup.  I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling RVM, XCode Command Line Tools, and even tried switching to rbenv.  Same outcome.

Any ideas?